# Disparando CSS transition ao realizar requisição ajax

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

Estou tentando fazer o seguinte, antes do elemento receber a resposta ajax eu seto o `opacity` dele pra `0` e disparo a transição, até ai esta funcionando beleza, a questão é que depois que eu passo o `responseText` pro elemento eu preciso exibir o elemento novamente e disparar a transição, mais não estou conseguindo fazer funcionar...

Eu ja consegui fazer isso com o `.show` e `.hide` do jquery mais queria fazer só ativando o css

```
document.getElementById( this.element ).addEventListener(
            "transitionend", 
            function(){
                document.getElementById( this.element ).innerHTML = this.xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById( this.element ).style.opacity = 1;
            }, true);
document.getElementById( this.element ).style.opacity = 0;
```

css do elemento

```
-webkit-transition: 200ms linear all;
-moz-transition: 200ms linear all;
transition: 200ms linear all;
```

// O problema esta com o `this` que esta retornando undefined, mas não sei como solucionar ;s

Comment: Mas você está usando o evento "transitionend", e não o callback do Ajax! Talvez o elemento esteja sendo exibido, só que sem conteúdo (innerHTML vazio). Experimente com `innerHTML = '<b>Oi, Mundo!</b>'` só para testar.

Comment: ja testei ele não esta mudando o innerHTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o `this` dentro da função *event handler* não corresponde mais ao `this` do contexto de execução fora dela. Experimente assim:

```
var self = this;
document.getElementById( self.element ).addEventListener(
            "transitionend", 
            function(){
                document.getElementById( self.element ).innerHTML = self.xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById( self.element ).style.opacity = 1;
            }, true);
document.getElementById( self.element ).style.opacity = 0;
```

---

Outra versão, melhorada:

```
var node = document.getElementById( this.element ),
    xhr  = this.xmlhttp;

node.addEventListener(
    "transitionend", 
    function() {
        if (node.style.opacity != 0) return;
        node.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        node.style.opacity = 1;
    }, true);
);

node.style.opacity = 0;
```

Comment: Então se eu faço só : opacity:0 elemento=response e opacity:1
funciona normal mais se coloco dentro do event listener ele não executa, se eu jogo só um alert vai mais se coloco o codigo não funciona

Comment: Tentou com `setTimeout`? Coloque `console.log` para verificar se `self.xmlhttp.responseText` contém mesmo alguma coisa e se `self.element` está realmente apontando para o elemento certo.

Comment: já testei com o setTimeout, ele ta dando esse erro no console tanto pra quando eu uso this quanto pra self -> Cannot read property 'responseText' of undefined

Comment: é realmente essa questão do this e do self pq se eu jogo direto la o nome do elemento ele funciona ;s

Comment: Experimente o novo código, onde definimos a variável `self` no lugar correto (veja a resposta alterada). Talvez assim nem seja necessário o `setTimeout`.

Comment: Mudei a resposta; por favor, verifique a nova solução.

Comment: Obrigado @J. Bruni  eu tinha acabado de conseguir mais atribuindo os valores da variaveis a outras fora do listener, porem apareceu outro problema, o event listener esta sendo executado duas vezes por causa das duas mudanças de opacity... alguma ideia de como solucionar ?

Comment: fiz um if pra só executar quando a opacity for 0 vlw ai a ajuda cara tu é fera

Comment: se tu puder editar a sua resposta pra ficar certinho adiciona o if ai -> if ( document.getElementById( self.element ).style.opacity == 0 ) {

Comment: Legal. Veja a "nova versão melhorada".

Answer (score 0):

Acho que com fadeIn() e fadeOut() ou talvez também com animate() pode te ajudar.

Comment: então brother como eu falei ali em cima eu ja consegui fazer isso com jquery, queria fazer sem, deixar possivel só ativar as transitions